# RIA service needs dummy public, non-attributed methods to compile

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am implementing a Silverlight application with a WCF RIA service in the server side and I am experiencing a very strange behavior.

At this point the service is very simple and only has a few methods, all of them marked with the `[Invoke]` attribute. These methods are something like this:

```
[Invoke]
MyEntity DoWorkAndReturnEntity(string someParameter)
{
    var entity = new MyEntity();
    //Do some preocessing...
    return entity;
}
```

where the `MyEntity` type has one public property with the `[Key]` attribute:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Key {get;set;}
}
```

Well, if I try to compile the solution, I get the following error:

> Operation named
>   'DoWorkAndReturnEntity' does not
>   conform to the required signature.
>   Return types must be an entity,
>   collection of entities, or one of the
>   predefined serializable types.

And now comes the funny part. If I add a public dummy method that returns an entity of the same type, but has **no** `Invoke` attribute, then it compiles and works perfectly!

```
public MyEntity __Dummy()
{
    return null;
}
```

This happens with all methods, regardless of the type of the object returned. So I have to add a dummy method for each returned object type.

I am completely puzzled. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity types are defined by the set of query methods in a domain service.

An invoke method cannot return an entity type unless it is one of the entities that are returned by the domain service... hence the __Dummy query method makes things work.

Answer (score 0):

WCF RIA Services uses configuration-by-convention, your `DoWorkAndReturnEntity` method needs to be decorated with the `[Query]` attribute or with no attribute at all since `[Query]` is the default just like in your `__Dummy` method.